# make4ht/ODT: resizing of images

Tags: graphics, luatex, tex4ht, open-office

There have already been several questions regarding the resizing of images with `ht4leax/make4ht`, but somehow none of the answers seems to resolve my problem.

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[]{fontspec} 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I compile this document with the following `make4ht` call to create a `.odt` file:

> make4ht -l -u -f odt test.tex

I tried all kind of different config files, I tried without and without `.xbb` files, but no matter what I do, the parameter given with `\includegraphics` is ignored and the size of the embedded image in the final document stays the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image dimension itself is set correctly, but it is embed in `draw:frame` element, which has wrong dimensions. I've found that this dimension is inserted  by Xtpipes, which reads the image dimension from the image file itself and ignores the dimensions set in the TeX file:

```xml
<draw:frame draw:name="film.jpg" text:anchor-type="as-char" draw:z-index="0" svg:width="41pt" svg:height="41pt"><draw:image xlink:href="Pictures/film.jpg" xlink:type="simple" xlink:show="embed" xlink:actuate="onLoad" svg:width="345.0pt" svg:height="345.1135pt"/><!--draw:name="IMG"                                                                         
 svg:width="345.0pt" svg:height="345.1135pt"                                                                                                                                                                    
 --></draw:frame>
```

It is possible to use `make4ht` filters to set the dimension in the `draw:frame` element to be the same as the dimension in the `draw:image`. Try the following build file:

```
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"

local domprocess = domfilter {
  function(dom)
    print("process images")
    local frames  = dom:query_selector("draw|frame")
    print("frames", #frames)
    for _, frame in ipairs(frames) do
      local images = frame:query_selector("draw|image")
      if #images > 0 then
        local image = images[1]
        local width = image:get_attribute("svg:width")
        local height = image:get_attribute("svg:height")
        frame:set_attribute("svg:width", width)
        frame:set_attribute("svg:height", height)
        print("image dimensions", width, height)
      end
    end
    return dom
  end
}

Make:match("4oo", domprocess)
```

It is still necessary to generate the `xbb` file using

```
ebb -x test.jpg
```

Sample result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That seems to do the trick. Any idea why this isn't standard behaviour?

Comment: @Simifilm I've added this to the development version of `make4ht`. I think no one reported this issue before