# make4ht/ODT: resizing of images outside of root compile directory

Tags: tex4ht, includegraphics, make4ht

While using the solution to this question [make4ht/ODT: resizing of images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447939/make4ht-odt-resizing-of-images), I observed that the solution and defaults behaviours worked, but this would break down if the images were placed in a sub folder.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    %\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a.jpg}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Lenna.png}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{./images/Lenna.png}

    \noindent
    %\includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-a.png}
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{Lenna.png}
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{./images/Lenna.png}

    will compile with all images of a default size if there is no xbb file

    will compile with properly sized images if Lenna.png \& Lenna.xbb are in the root folder

    will not compile with images if Lenna.png \& Lenna.xbb are in a sub folder

    will not compile with images if Lenna.png is in a sub folder but Lenna.xbb is in the root folder

\end{document}
```

Relative to the original linked question, I observed the make4ht filter is no longer necessary, but the manual creation of the *.xbb files still are.

Is anything special needed to patch or ensure that the full relative file name (+path) are preserved using make4ht?

Side note:  I never got example-image-a.jpg to resize properly, I assume because there was no xbb file, let alone one in the root level of the file.

Comment: I Will be offline for next two weeks, so it will take some time before I will be able to answer

Answer (score 1):

I guess that this may depend on operating system and web browser. Your example works for me in Firefox on Linux. `tex4ht` doesn't attempt to change the image names in the HTML mode, other than changing the image extension in the case of conversion from EPS to SVG, etc. I would suggest to drop the leading `./` and use just

```
 \includegraphics{images/Lenna.png}
```

instead.

Regarding the image size issue, you can try the following config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\def\ifboundingbox#1#2{%
\ifdim\Gin@req@width=\Gin@nat@width\ifx\noBoundingBox\UnDefined#1\else#2\fi\else#1\fi
}
\def\int@pt#1.#2!*?: {#1}
   \Configure{Gin-dim}
     {\ifboundingbox{width="\expandafter\int@pt\the\Gin@req@width!*?: " height="\expandafter\int@pt\the\Gin@req@height!*?: "}{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Here is a modified sample:

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/501648/2891
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    %\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a.jpg}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Lenna.png}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{./images/Lenna.png}

    \noindent
    %\includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-a.png}
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{Lenna.png}
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{./images/Lenna.png}

    \noindent
    \includegraphics[]{Lenna.png}
    \includegraphics[]{images/Lenna.png}

\end{document}
```

In this example, I've put the xbb file to the images subdir

[image]

This is the generated HTML code:

```html
<!--l. 5--><p class="noindent" ><img 
src="Lenna.png" alt="PIC"  
width="56" height="56"  /> <img 
src="./images/Lenna.png" alt="PIC"  
width="56" height="56"  />
</p><!--l. 10--><p class="noindent" ><img 
src="Lenna.png" alt="PIC"  
width="227" height="227"  /> <img 
src="./images/Lenna.png" alt="PIC"  
width="227" height="227"  />
</p><!--l. 15--><p class="noindent" ><img 
src="Lenna.png" alt="PIC"  
 /> <img 
src="images/Lenna.png" alt="PIC"  
width="513" height="513"  />
```